# Jquery image slider/fader shortly shows all images in the beginning

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm implementing the following script into my website.
https://www.jqueryscript.net/slideshow/Simple-Responsive-Background-Image-Cycler-With-jQuery.html

However, when the site is visited, the images are visible for a split second (they flash by). This is strange because the (creator of the) code says the container is hidden until all images are loaded.

by the way, in the original code #background-cycler has a z-index of -1. I had to change this to 1, otherwise the entire thing is invisible (probably behind `body` or something.

```js
function cycleImages(){
  var $active = $('#background_cycler .active');
  var $next = ($('#background_cycler .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#background_cycler .active').next() : $('#background_cycler .img:first');
  $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
  $active.fadeOut(1000,function(){//fade out the top image
    $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
    $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
  });
}

$(window).load(function(){
  $('#background_cycler').css('visibility','visible');
  $('#background_cycler').fadeIn(1000);//fade the background back in once all the images are loaded
  // run every 5s
  setInterval('cycleImages()', 5000);
})
```

```css
#background_cycler {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility:hidden;
display:none;
}

#background_cycler .img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#background_cycler .img.active { z-index: 3; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Background Image Cycler Demo</title>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="background_cycler" >
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#background_cycler').hide(); //hide the background while the images load, ready to fade in later
 </script>

 <div class="img active" style="background:url('https://unsplash.it/1920/1200?image=1074') top left no-repeat; background-size:cover;"></div>
 <div class="img" style="background:url('https://unsplash.it/1920/1200?image=1072') top left no-repeat; background-size:cover;"></div>
 <div class="img" style="background:url('https://unsplash.it/1920/1200?image=1071') top left no-repeat; background-size:cover;"></div>
 <div class="img" style="background:url('https://unsplash.it/1920/1200?image=1070') top left no-repeat; background-size:cover;"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why all the custom scripting? What are you trying to do that the plugin doesn't?

Comment: This is known as a Flash of Unstyled Content (or FOUC), and it happens as the DOM (and all the images it contains) loads before JS can safely interact with it. As such, all the images appear by default, then disappear when told to by JS. The quick fix for this is to have the images load in a hidden container, then show the container just before you start the slideshow

Comment: The `$('#background_cycler').hide();` is advised on the mentioned site. It does however not say whether is should go at the top of the document, or at the bottom.

Comment: You're better off ignoring that completely as it will have the same problem. Use CSS to hide the container.

Comment: So set #background_cycler to `visibiliy:hidden` and then let the javascript set it to visibility:visible?

Comment: It's not. You need to set `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` in your CSS, then remove/override it when the page has loaded.

Comment: I've set background_cycler to `display:none` in CSS. I will test whether that helps.